# Store the checked checkbox value and it's name in a two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to store the checked checkbox value and it's name in a two dimensional array,
here is html code.

```
<h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="football" name="football"> Football</label>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="baseball"> Baseball</label>
```

And I can only display the checked checbox values, here is jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var favorite = [];
        $.each($("input:checked"), function () {
            favorite.push($(this).val());
        });
        alert("My favourite sports are: " + favorite);
    });
});
```

My question is how to store both values and It's name in favorite array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**Array of objects**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742442/declaring-array-of-objects) for this:

```
favorite.push({
   name: $(this).attr('name'),
   value:$(this).val()
});
```

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/boah1wp8/)

Output:

```
[{
    "name": "football",
    "value": "football"
}, {
    "name": "baseball",
    "value": "baseball"
}]
```

---

If you want to display values:

```
$.each(favorite, function(index, obj){
   console.log("Name= "+ obj.name+"  Value="+ obj.value);
})
```

Comment: It returns object, how can i assign name and value to variable?

Comment: It doesn't return `Object` it will return `Array` of objects. You can easily assign value in it.

Comment: Can you please more clarify , how will i assign to variable, I have no idea about it, thanks!

Comment: Tell me what value you wants to assign to `favorite`?

Comment: I want to display like this, 
output: checkbox name ="here the checkbox name" and Its value is = "here It's value"

Answer (score 1):

use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)**.Translate all items in an array or object

```
var favorite= $("input:checked").map(function () {
    var obj = {};
    obj[$(this).attr('name')] = this.value;
    return obj;

}).get();

console.log(favorite)
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4pounzvg/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Use array of objects

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        var favorite = [];
        $.each($("input:checked"), function () {

            // Add object in array
            favorite.push({
                name: $(this).attr('name'),
                value: $(this).val()
            });
        });
        console.log("My favourite sports are: ");
        console.log(favorite);
    });
});
```

Comment: How will i assign to variable these name and value?

Comment: `window[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val()`