# using Array.fill or from to create m by n array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to create a `[m, n]` sized array pre-filled with 0 in ES6

```
var x = Array.from(Array(5), () => 0)
```

gives a array of length 5. I need one with 5x3

```
var x = Array.from(Array(Array.from(Array(3),()=>0)), () => 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array with `n` zeros:

```
Array(n).fill(0)
```

Create an array which contains `m` times the same array with `n` zeros:

```
Array(m).fill(Array(n).fill(0));
```

Create an array which contains `m` different arrays with `n` zeros:

```
Array(m).fill().map(() => Array(n).fill(0));
```

Example:

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify( Array(5).fill().map(() => Array(3).fill(0)) ));
```

Comment: Also see [Most efficient way to create a zero filled JavaScript array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1295584/1529630) and [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35578478/1529630)

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect do it like

```js
var x = Array.from(Array(5), () => Array.from(Array(3), () => 0));

console.log(x);
```