# Create nested JavaScript array of specific size

Tags: javascript, arrays

I’m trying to combine 3 arrays into one "2d array":

```
resultArr = [
  ["abc", 0, []],
  ["def", 0, []],
  ["ghi", 0, []],
  ["jkl", 0, []],
  ["mno", 0, []],
  ["pqr", 0, []],
  ["stu", 0, []]
];
```

Basically, I’m starting with an arbitrary array as my input, such as `snippets`:

**Array 1:**

```
const snippets = ['abc', "def", "ghi", "jkl", "mno", "pqr", "stu"];
```

The next steps was easy, I created a an array filled with zeros:

**Array 2:**

```
const zeros = new Array(snippets.length).fill(0); // [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now, I tried the same to get a list of empty arrays:

**Array 3:**

```
const zeroArr = new Array(snippets.length).fill([]); // → circular object arrays :(
```

Obviously, fill cannot handle nested arrays `.fill([])` or `.fill([[]])`. Is there any way to create this nested array structure?

FYI: I continue to combine these rows like so, it works if I would leave out the last `, zeroArr[0][i]]` part:

```
  let combined = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < genreLength; i++) {
    combined.push([snippets[i], zeros[i], zeroArr[0][i]]);
  }
```

Comment: `snippets.map(e => [e, 0, []])` ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Are the second and third input arrays always zeros and empty arrays? Or is this just an example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - why Array.prototype.fill actually fills a "pointer" of object when filling anything like 'new Object()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38940576/javascript-why-array-prototype-fill-actually-fills-a-pointer-of-object-when)

Comment: @Attersson They are always zeros / empty arrays. The zeros act as a counter in a later step and also the array, gets filled with some string entries.

Comment: @McTell Do what Nenad Vracar said then.

Comment: @NenadVracar, works! Thanks!