# Changing values in nested JS arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

The following code should create an empty array that contains 7 empty arrays, effectively a 7x7 grid.

Accessing elements in nested arrays works fine, but trying to change their values changes the value of all elements in the same column (so changing [1][1] also changes [0][1], [2][1] etc.). I can't understand why.

```
var usage = new Array(7).fill(new Array(7).fill(0));

usage[1][1] += 1;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v3o4rwsz/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an easy trap to fall into. Your code is equivalent to:

```
var innerArray = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; // .fill(0)
var usage = [innerArray, innerArray, innerArray, innerArray,
             innerArray, innerArray, innerArray]; // .fill(innerArray)

console.log(usage[0]==innerArray); // true
console.log(usage[1]==innerArray); // true
```

To get the result you want, you need to create a new array for each element in usage, e.g:

```
var usage = [];
for (var i=0; i<7; i++) {
    usage.push(new Array(7).fill(0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the first `fill` is only evaluating once - creating the second array, and then it is duplicating that array 7 times, so they are all connected.

It is the equivalent to:

```
var t1 = new Array(7).fill(0);

var t2 = t1;
var t3 = t1;
var t4 = t1;
var t5 = t1;
var t6 = t1;
var t7 = t1;

t2[3] = "duplicate"

console.log(t1);
console.log(t2);
console.log(t3);
```

Which will show the same value in `t1` to `t7`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this behaviour is caused by your use of `.fill()`. If you look at the definition of that [function here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) you'll see it populates an array with a **static value**

This means that when you reference `usage[1][1]` you are referencing the same array that exists in `usage[0][1]`, `usage[2][1]` and so on.

You can populate the array with a for loop, like below.

```
var usage2 = new Array();

for(var i=0;i<7;i++) { 
    usage2.push(new Array(7).fill(0));
}
```

Now when you check your values you'll see the expected result where only one array is altered, like in the below screenshot from my Chrome console.

[image: JS Console Screenshot]