# Changing one array element affects other elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a javascript code as below.

```js
var row = new Array(7);
row.fill(0);
var state = new Array(7);
state.fill(row);
state[0][3] = 2;
console.log(state);
```

My issue is, when I change one element `state[0][3] = 2;` it affects all rows. All rows 3rd index value becomes 2. Can someone tell what is wrong in this code?

Comment: this line `state.fill(row);` will **apply** `row` array to each `state` item - by **reference**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can someone tell what is wrong in this code?

You're using **one** `row` array for **all** your entries in `state`. `fill` takes the *value* you give it and puts that value in the target array repeatedly. The value you're giving it is a reference to the single array you've created, so **all** of those entries end up referring to the *same* row, like this:

```
                                          +−−−−−−−−−+
row−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−+−+−+−+−+−+−−>| (array) |
          +−−−−−−−−−+     | | | | | | |   +−−−−−−−−−+
state−−−−>| (array) |     | | | | | | |   | 0: 0    |
          +−−−−−−−−−+     | | | | | | |   | 1: 0    |
          | 0       |−−−−−+ | | | | | |   | 2: 0    |
          | 1       |−−−−−−−+ | | | | |   | 3: 0    |
          | 2       |−−−−−−−−−+ | | | |   | 4: 0    |
          | 3       |−−−−−−−−−−−+ | | |   | 5: 0    |
          | 4       |−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ | |   | 6: 0    |
          | 5       |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |   +−−−−−−−−−+
          | 6       |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
          +−−−−−−−−−+
```

You'll need to create a new row array for *each* slot in `state`:

```js
let state = Array.from({length:7}, () => {
  return new Array(7).fill(0);
});
state[0][3] = 2;
console.log(state);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...or with only features present in ES5:

```js
var state = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0].map(function() {
  return [0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
});
state[0][3] = 2;
console.log(state);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```