# I can't figure out what's going on. I add an object to the array, it is added, but the old data copies the values from the new object. Problem

Tags: javascript, arrays, copy

I can't figure out what's going on. I add an object to the array, it is added, but the old data copies the values from the new object. This is the first time I've encountered this.

Here is the code

```
      var next
      if(cart === null){
        next = 0
      }else {
        next = cart.length
      }
      switch(type){
        case 'horizontal':
          config['0']['type'] = type
          config['0']['id'] = next
          config['0'].idImg = selectSvg
          if(cart === null || cart === undefined || cart.length < 1){
            const news = []
            news.push(config)
            setCountCart(news.length)
            localStorage.setItem('cart-tagstyle', JSON.stringify(news))
            setCart(news)
          }else {
            const news = [...cart]
            console.log(news);
            news.push(config)
            console.log(news);
            setCountCart(news.length)
            localStorage.setItem('cart-tagstyle', JSON.stringify(news))
            setCart(news)
          }
          break;
```

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I tried it without push, according to the following index, the same thing. I searched the Internet, it didn't help. I've been suffering for the second day

Comment: What is `config` and where do you create it? Are you sure that it is a new object each time your code above runs? Seems like your issue might be that it's not and you're changing the same object reference each time.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure this is a constructor config, it is reset when added to the cart. It's from another component. It's not about him, I've already checked.

Comment: It’s not clear what specific observation you’re referring to, but from the description this is almost certainly an issue where you have multiple references to the same object and are expecting different objects.  Can you update this to a [mcve] which can be executed to demonstrate the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example?

Comment: [^^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78096322/i-cant-figure-out-whats-going-on-i-add-an-object-to-the-array-it-is-added-b#comment137679846_78096322) That is, a problem [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46602139/changing-one-array-element-affects-other-elements).