# Usage of Spread Operator in Array().fill()

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, pass-by-reference, spread-syntax

When using a spread operator, a new object is created so:

```
const foo = { a: 1 }
const m1 = {...foo}
const m2 = {...foo}
m1 === m2 // false
```

However, when using Array.fill(), this is not the case:

```
const m3 = Array(2).fill({...foo})
m3[0] === m3[1] // true
```

I have tried this a few different ways but I always end up with .fill() passing by reference and not creating a new object. Any idea why this is happening?

Alternatives I have tried:

where foo creates a new object every time it is called.
I've tried this both with spread and without

```
const foo = () => ({ a: 1 })
const m4 = Array(2).fill({...foo()}) 
m4[0] === m4[1] // true
```

where the array is defined before hand and spread operator is also used in .fill().

```
const m5 = Array(2)
m5.fill({...foo()})
m5[0] === m5[1] // true
```

Comment: [This question has already been answered here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance)

Comment: also `Array.from({length:2}, _ => ({...foo}))`

Comment: In `Array(2).fill({...foo})`, a new object *is* created because of the object literal, just like in your first snippet. Then that single object is passed into `fill`.