# How do I use array.fill for creating an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In the following javascript snippet, why are elements in `tedious` and `concise` not equivalent when you run this snippet?
I get `/**ref:2**/` output for `concise` from the second element.

```js
const tedious = [
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
];

const concise = new Array(9).fill({});

console.log(tedious);
console.log(concise);
```

Comment: Maybe the interpreter of this snippet does not fully support es6? Works fine for me using Chrome console...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with “error” or “does not fully support es6”. Of _course_ snippets support ES6. How could they not? `/**ref:2**/` means “reference to element 2 of the array”, since the console feature of Stack Snippets can’t know whether you’ve got an infinitely nested structure, so instead the `ref` comments (and `id` comments which aren’t used in this case) are used.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note: not sure what is happening in running a snippet, but that ref business does not happen in the real world

> as per Xufox comment: `/**ref:2**/` means “reference to element 2 of the array”, since the console feature of Stack Snippets can’t know whether you’ve got an infinitely nested structure, so instead the ref comments (and id comments which aren’t used in this case) are used

The **real** problem with

```
const concise = new Array(9).fill({});
```

IS that all 9 entries will "refer" to the same object - see the output

```js
const concise = new Array(9).fill({}); // {} 
concise[0].a='hello world';
console.log(JSON.stringify(concise))
```

To better illustrate that, let's pass a non-empty object to `fill` with a random value

```js
const concise = new Array(9).fill({random:Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)});
console.log(JSON.stringify(concise))
```

Clearly, that object is created exactly once

Try

```js
const concise = new Array(9).fill(0).map(() => ({}));

concise[0].a='hello world';
console.log(JSON.stringify(concise))
```

as the map callback is called once for each element, a new object is created each time

Or you can try

```js
const concise = Array.from({length:9}, () => ({}));

concise[0].a='hello world';
console.log(JSON.stringify(concise))
```

the second argument to `Array.from` is a callback that is called once for each element, it's basically the same `.map`

And of course, thanks to @Slai, the above is even more simply

```
const concise = Array.from({length:9}, Object);
```

---

Compare the output of the "math random" code above with

```js
const concise = Array.from({length:9}, () => ({random:Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}));
console.log(JSON.stringify(concise))
```

Comment: `/**ref:2**/` means “reference to element 2 of the array”, since the console feature of Stack Snippets can’t know whether you’ve got an infinitely nested structure, so instead the `ref` comments (and `id` comments which aren’t used in this case) are used.

Comment: Fair enough, what stack snippets actually does is irrelevant anyway, as the OP would have issues they were not even aware of :p

Comment: "When the fill method gets passed an object, it will copy the reference and fill the array with references to that object." 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

I guess that's what I missed. Thanks for this answer, very insightful.

Comment: `const concise = Array.from({length:9}, () => ({random:Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)})) 

console.log(concise);`

can you add this in your answer? would be very illustrative

Comment: added that @Gallaxhar