# Pushing to an array inside an object references the pushed object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation, push

The snippet is detailing my problem. I have an object that stores an array of objects (some of which are arrays). When I push to these internal arrays, that value pushes to all of the elements in the array instead of just the index I'm looking for.

I feel like this should be a really easy fix - but I've tried everything. Switching to concat,push,putting things into for loops. When I run a simplified version in the snippet - (see snippet below) - then it says there's a "ref" to a certain ID. I'm not sure what this means, but my guess is that someone does know! any help would be great.

```js
const runs = {
  AC: {
    L: Array(10).fill({
      stim: [],
      mask: [],
      resp: [],
      other: []
    }),
    R: Array(10).fill({
      stim: [],
      mask: [],
      resp: [],
      other: []
    })
  },
}

let runData = runs["AC"]["R"][3]

runData.stim.push(40)

console.log(runs.AC.R)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filling the array with the same reference. Instead, fill the array with empty items, then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to insert the object:

```js
runs = {
  AC: {
    L: Array(10).fill().map(e=>({
      stim: [],
      mask: [],
      resp: [],
      other: []
    })),
    R: Array(10).fill().map(e=>({
      stim: [],
      mask: [],
      resp: [],
      other: []
    }))
  },      
}

let runData = runs["AC"]["R"][3]

runData.stim.push(40)

console.log(runs.AC.R)
```

Comment: oh my goodness. thank you. Will accept an answer after the 10-minute window :)

Comment: also - for the next person: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807131/how-do-i-use-array-fill-for-creating-an-array-of-objects