# How to generate an unique id for each Component of initial value of useState()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lifecycle

I want to create 30 empty Taskcard components at the beginning of the state my problem is that each Taskcard has the same id how can I fix that?

```html
import React from 'react'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getTasks } from '../api/task.api'
import { TaskCard } from './TaskCard'


export function TaskLists() {
    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(Array(30).fill({id: 1, title: 'title', description: 'description'}))

   useEffect(() => {
     async function loadTasks() {
        const res = await getTasks();
        console.log(res.data)
        setTasks(res.data);
     }
     loadTasks();
   },[]);

   const removeTask = (id) => {
        setTasks(tasks.filter(task => task.id !== id));
   }

  return (
    <div>
        {tasks.map((task) => (
            <TaskCard key={task.id} task={task} onDelete={removeTask} />
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: `fill()`ing with an object fills it with references to the same object. see the docs: [Array.prototype.fill()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#value)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I use array.fill for creating an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50807131/how-do-i-use-array-fill-for-creating-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: But more curiously you are setting an initial array, and then immediately overwriting it with the fetched data in the useEffect.

Comment: @pilchard how can I fix all of this?

Comment: @pilchard thanks for the reference but as you see it does not answer my question because I end up overwriting with use effect that's my main issue...-

Comment: Your question is about initial state value, and the flagged duplicate does answer that question. As for the fetched value, you have not shown any details about what `getTasks()` returns.

Comment: thats a get request form an api

Comment: @pilchard Is there any way that the API gets mounted with 30 cardtask on not get another 30 when refreshing the page?

Comment: It wont get another 30, as you are setting tasks state in useEffect,and on load first useEffect will be called every time.

Comment: I dont know what UX you want, but the best thing here you can do is to show loader before you get API response, and then directly show correct data instead of dummy data.

Comment: @MrJonesBones You have accepted an answer that is identical to the duplicate even though you stated that that doesn't answer your question.

Comment: @pilchard yea did not notice the database update deleting the 30 taskcards

Answer (score 0):

Try, this hosuld work

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([...Array(10).keys()].map(x => { return {id: x+1, title: 'title', description: 'description'}}))
```

Comment: This is covered in the flagged duplicate. Vote to close instead