# Populating a 2D array in Javascript with random numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, random, auto-populating

I'm trying to populate a 2D array in javascript with random numbers.  Although each column in the array is random, each row is identical which is not what I want (see image below).  I want both rows and columns to be random.

http://eeldesigns.com/image.jpg

```
cols = 5;
rows = 10;

front = new Array(cols).fill(new Array(rows));

// Loop through Initial array to randomly place cells
for(var x = 0; x < cols; x++){
  for(var y = 0; y < rows; y++){
    front[x][y] = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
  }
}
console.table(front) ;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance)

Comment: `.fill(new Array(rows))` creates a single array instance and assigns it to each column. So when you think you modify only one you actually modify all of them. It's as if you were doing this: https://jsfiddle.net/ejqc4z8x/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that you're not initializing the row.  It's easily fixed:

```js
cols = 5;
rows = 10;

front = new Array(cols)// .fill(new Array(rows));

// Loop through Initial array to randomly place cells
for(var x = 0; x < cols; x++){
  front[x] = [];  // ***** Added this line *****
  for(var y = 0; y < rows; y++){
    front[x][y] = Math.floor(Math.random()*5);
  }
}
console.table(front) ; // browser console only, not StackOverflow's
```

### Update

This is a cleaner version, somewhat similar to the one from Code Maniac, but simplified a bit:

```js
const randomTable = (rows, cols) => Array.from(
  {length: rows}, 
  () => Array.from({length: cols}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))
)

console.table(randomTable(10, 5)) // browser console only, not StackOverflow's
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Just a quick question  - does not the 'new Array()' initalise the row?

Comment: Note that although this shows where you went wrong, the answer from Code Maniac is a better solution.

Comment: No, and I should have commented that out before.  You're passing one value to `fill`, which is used to fill all the rows with the same empty array.  That's one reason the other answer is cleaner.

Comment: Added a cleaner version.

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let op = new Array(10)
         .fill(0)
         .map(e=>(new Array(5)
         .fill(0)
         .map(e=> Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))))

console.log(op)
```

Comment: thanks for the tip - I wasn't familiar with maps and their usage.

Comment: @Ismail always happy to help :) you can read about map on given link in answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using a combination of `Array.prototype.fill()` and `Array.prototype.map()`:

```
new Array(rows).fill([]).map(x => Array(columns).fill(0).map(x => x + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min));
```

For example, we can create a 100 by 964 column array full of random numbers between 900 and 1000 using the following:

```
new Array(100).fill([]).map(x => Array(964).fill(0).map(x => x + Math.floor(Math.random() * (1000 - 900)) + 900));
```