# Create 2D Array without looping - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to create 2D array in js without looping?

Wanna get something like this:

```
[
    [number, number, number],
    [number, number, number], 
    [number, number, number],
]
```

Comment: What is your intended output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested map()

```js
const randomNum = (min, max) => {
    return Math.trunc(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
const createRandom2DArray = (rows, columns) => [...Array(rows)].map(x => [...Array(columns)].map(x => randomNum(1,5)));

console.log(createRandom2DArray(5,5))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const randomTable = (rows, cols) => Array.from(
  {length: rows}, 
  () => Array.from({length: cols}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 5))
)

console.table(randomTable(10, 5)) // browser console only, not StackOverflow's
```

source: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523526/populating-a-2d-array-in-javascript-with-random-numbers)