# Binding to an array of objects inside an ngFor, binds all inputs together

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to create a registration form for an array of persons with Angular. Persons are in an array of *Person* objects.
The problem is that all input fields are bind together!
I did this with a *String[]* and it works like a charm but when using Person 
class it misbehaves!

[image]

This is my component:

**Stackblitz.com:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m5xzds

**TS file:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

class Person {
  constructor(
    firstname: string,
    lastname: string) { }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  array = Array;
  count = 3;
  persons: Person[];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.persons = new Array<Person>(5).fill({});
  }
}
```

**Template:**

```
count: <input type="number" name="count" [(ngModel)]="count">
<div>Persons:</div>

<div *ngFor="let item of array(count).fill(0); index as i">
  <form>
<input [(ngModel)]="persons[i].firstname" type="text" class="form-control" name="name_{{i}}">

  </form>
</div>
{{persons|json}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `Array.fill` method passes the reference so it's basically the same object in the five places of your persons array, it was working with string array because string are immutable and the array is full of 'different' strings. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance).

So you can use a map function to solve that as in the question or separate the `ngmodel` and the `ngmodelchange` see example here: [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rvfys6)

Answer (score 2):

*ngFor can loop over your list of persons directly, i feel like you could simplify this by doing the following.

```
  <form>
<div *ngFor="let person of persons; let i = index">
<input *ngIf="i < count" [(ngModel)]="person.firstname" type="text" class="form-control" name="{{person.firstname}}">  
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: There should only be one form tag

Comment: name attribute cannot be {{person.name}}.But beside that, your code is not working. . Check the new stackblitz: stackblitz.com/edit/rostamiani-angular-foreach-answer

Comment: Thanks, Good idea. but the solution is what @hakimovic said.