# format JSON object into array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, browser

I want to convert the below JSON format

```
let init = {
  test1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  test2: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}
```

into this format using javascript native methods of array or object (supported in all browsers)

```
[{
  test1: 1,
  test2: 6
},{
  test1: 2,
  test2: 7
},{
  test1: 3,
  test2: 8
},{
  test1: 4,
  test2: 9
},{
  test1: 5,
  test2: 10
}]
```

I have tried with for loop and below is the code,

```
let keys = Object.keys(init);
let result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
   let key = keys[i];
   for(let j = 0; j < init[key].length; j++){
      if(i === 0){
        let obj1 = {};
        obj1[key] = init[key][j];
        result.push(obj1);
    }else{
        let obj2 = result[j];
        obj2[key] = init[key][j];
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add what you've tried so far? Thanks!

Comment: Nick, I have used simply for loop, but I want to do this with javascript native methods and couldn't think any approach on this

Comment: @ggorlen I have posted my attempt using for loop. As I am currently new on using JS native methods that's why I have used for loop. For more clarity on grouping logic, I have changed the test2 property value

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do that.

Iterate on `test1` array elements and push a new object to the array accumulator with `test1` and `test2` properties and their respective values.

```js
let init = {
  test1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  test2: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
};

let keys = Object.keys(init);
let key1 = keys[0];
let key2 = keys[1];

let result = init[key1].reduce((acc, curr, i) => {
  acc.push({
    [key1]: curr,
    [key2]: init[key2][i]
  });

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

As of now, `reduce()` method is [supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_reduce) in most of the modern browsers. For supporting all browsers, it is better to use `for` loop, but instead of `Object.keys()` iterate on object properties or use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill).

```js
let init = {
  test1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  test2: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
};

let keys = [];

for (let key in init) {
  if (init.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    keys.push(key);
  }
}

let key1 = keys[0];
let key2 = keys[1];

let result = [];

for (let i = 0; i < key1.length; i++) {
  result.push({
    [key1]: init[key1][i],
    [key2]: init[key2][i]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Though if I have more than two properties in init object say test1 to testn having the same length of arrays, then I think in reduce function we need to add for loop

Comment: That's right @NarenderSaharan — a `for` loop to iterate on object keys.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a combination of for...in and Array.forEach to achieve this result in a few lines of code. If you wan't support for all browsers you can better use *var* instead of  *let* though. https://caniuse.com/#search=let

```js
var init = {
  test1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  test2: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}

var result = []
for (var key in init) {
  init[key].forEach(function (item, index) {
    result[index] ? result[index][key] = item : result[index] = { [key]: item }
  })
}

console.log(result)
```

You could maybe simplify this a bit more by initializing your result with empty objects, that would avoid using a ternary statement. That would look like this:

**Disclaimer**: This won't work in IE11 because of the lack of Array.fill() support

```js
var init = {
  test1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  test2: [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
}

var result = new Array(Object.keys(init)[0].length).fill().map(Object);
for (var key in init) {
  init[key].forEach(function(item, index) {
    result[index][key] = item
  })
}

console.log(result)
```

If you do this make sure you don't create an array with Objects that are a reference to the same object in memory: [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance)