# Strange behaviour of array fill?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I get strange results in my code.

```
function myFunction() {
  var arrT = new Array(2)
  arrT.fill('-');
  var arrR = new Array(4);
  arrR.fill(arrT);



  console.log(arrR); // returns [ [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ] ]
  arrR[0][1]='xxx'
  console.log(arrR); // returns [ [ '-', 'xxx' ], [ '-', 'xxx' ], [ '-', 'xxx' ], [ '-', 'xxx' ] ]

}
```

I need a prefilled 2D-array (here I define it fixed but normally the dimension is calculated)
I thought I use the fill method and it seemed to work fine.
but when I try to put a value in a cell, all rows are filled.

What i'm doing wrong? I expected to have [ [ '-', 'xxx' ], [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ] ]

Many thanks in advance,

Filip

Comment: Related: [Array.prototype.fill() with object passes reference and not new instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance) – `.fill()` only copies the primitive value. With `.fill(arrT)`, the primitive is an object reference. So, `arrR` is filled with 4 references all pointing to the same array object. You'll have to create the copies of the array yourself (e.g. `arrT.slice()`).

Answer (score 1):

If you fill with array `arrR` with array `arrT`, all elements of `arrR` will be `arrT` and not a copy of array `arrT`. Use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [`.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to make a copy:

```js
  var arrT = new Array(2)
  arrT.fill('-');
  var arrR = new Array(4).fill(null).map(_=>arrT.slice());



  console.log(arrR); // returns [ [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ] ]
  arrR[0][1]='xxx'
  console.log(arrR); // returns [ [ '-', 'xxx' ], [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ], [ '-', '-' ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I used a simple loop as it should be faster than the map-slice solution (stated in the related question).

Greetings,