# Angularjs binding updates all selects in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

When I'm using ng-model inside of ng-repeat it updates all ng-models inside that repeat loop. If I remove datatype and directly set to myCtrl.data[$index] it works fine.

Any suggestions?

template:

```
<div ng-repeat="i in myCtrl.data track by $index">
   <div>
      <div>
         <select
            ng-model="myCtrl.data[$index].datatype"
            ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in myCtrl.detailTypes track by item.label"
         >
            <option value="" disabled selected>
               select an option
            </option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

controller:

```
self.detailTypes = [
   {label: 'KEY_1', value: 'VAL_1'},
   {label: 'KEY_2', value: 'VAL_2'},
];

self.data = new Array(2).fill({dataType: null});
```

When I select KEY_1 for first select, it changes object to [{dataType: 'VAL_1'}, {dataType: 'VAL_1'}]

Comment: I tried your code but could not reproduce this behavior when I used a function in ng-change for the selects populated in the ng-repeat. Does your template use only one controller?

Comment: Weird but I found out the problem. I replace new Array(2).fill({dataType: null}); with push values in a loop. Problem is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so this is happening because you are populating your self.data with Array.fill which when used with objects, [passes by reference not value.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance)

If you change declaration of your self.data to this

```
self.data = [];
self.data.push({dataType:null},{dataType:null});
```

it will work.