# Array.fill() then changeing the value in a 2D array gives the same output for a column in JS

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array, deno

so i filled this 2D array with 0
and then changing the first value in the first row of this 2D array
but it changes the first value in every row, anyone know why this is happening?

```
let arr = Array<number[]>(5).fill(Array<number>(5).fill(0));

arr[0][0] = 10;
console.log(arr);
```

output

```
[
  [ 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]
```

expected output

````
[
  [ 10, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
  [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]```
````

Comment: This is not related to Deno this is hows Array.fill works, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Array.prototype.fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) sets each element in the array to the specified value. To generate an array filled with possibly different values you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
let arr = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => Array<number>(5).fill(0));
```

Comment: so it is the same value/pointer for all values in a the columns, i understood it now, thank you.