# Working on transforming array object data where it's taking same value for each indexes while converting it to other format

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, transformation, pure-js

I have an issue transforming array object data into required format. With my solution it's transforming it correctly but it's copying same last index data for each item in array.

##### Input:

```
let data = [
  {
    0: {
      value1: true,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    1: {
      value1: true,
      value2: true,
      isSelected: true,
    },
    2: {
      value1: false,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    3: {
      value1: false,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    4: {
      value1: true,
      value2: true,
      isSelected: true,
    },
    Stage: 'A',
  },
  {
    0: {
      value1: false,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    1: {
      value1: true,
      value2: true,
      isSelected: true,
    },
    2: {
      value1: false,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    3: {
      value1: false,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    4: {
      value1: true,
      value2: true,
      isSelected: true,
    },
    Stage: 'B',
  },
  {
    0: {
      value1: false,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    1: {
      value1: true,
      value2: true,
      isSelected: true,
    },
    2: {
      value1: false,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    3: {
      value1: false,
      value2: false,
      isSelected: false,
    },
    4: {
      value1: true,
      value2: true,
      isSelected: true,
    },
    Stage: 'C',
  },
];
```

##### Expected output:

```
// Expected output data
[
  {
    Stage: [
      {
        value1: true,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: true,
        value2: true,
        isSelected: true,
      },
      {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: true,
        value2: true,
        isSelected: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    Stage: [
      {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: true,
        value2: true,
        isSelected: true,
      },
      {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: true,
        value2: true,
        isSelected: true,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    Stage: [
      {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: true,
        value2: true,
        isSelected: true,
      },
      {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: false,
        value2: false,
        isSelected: false,
      },
      {
        value1: true,
        value2: true,
        isSelected: true,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

##### What I've tried:

```
stagesBackTransform = (data) => {
  let newArr = new Array(data.length).fill({ Stage: new Array(16) });

  data.forEach((stage, stageIdx) => {
    Object.entries(stage).forEach((item, idx) => {
      if (item[0] !== 'Stage') {
        // newArr[stageIdx].Stage[item[0]] = item[1];
        newArr[stageIdx].Stage[idx] = item[1];
      }
    });
  });
  console.log('new:', newArr);
  return newArr;
};
```

```js
let data = [
  {
    0: { value1: true, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    1: { value1: true, value2: true, isSelected: true },
    2: { value1: false, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    3: { value1: false, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    4: { value1: true, value2: true, isSelected: true },
    Stage: 'A',
  },
  {
    0: { value1: false, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    1: { value1: true, value2: true, isSelected: true },
    2: { value1: false, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    3: { value1: false, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    4: { value1: true, value2: true, isSelected: true },
    Stage: 'B',
  },
  {
    0: { value1: false, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    1: { value1: true, value2: true, isSelected: true },
    2: { value1: false, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    3: { value1: false, value2: false, isSelected: false },
    4: { value1: true, value2: true, isSelected: true },
    Stage: 'C',
  },
];

stagesBackTransform = (data) => {
  let newArr = new Array(data.length).fill({ Stage: new Array(16) });

  data.forEach((stage, stageIdx) => {
    Object.entries(stage).forEach((item, idx) => {
      if (item[0] !== 'Stage') {
        // newArr[stageIdx].Stage[item[0]] = item[1];
        newArr[stageIdx].Stage[idx] = item[1];
      }
    });
  });
  console.log('new:', newArr);
  return newArr;
};

const result = stagesBackTransform(data);

console.log(result);
```

It's giving me output in expected format but it's copying same item[1] which is object. It's copying last index object at all indexes in newly created arr.
What mistake I'm doing here in my current code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use `.map` and [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to transform array

Live Demo:

```js
let data = [{"0": {"value1": true,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"1": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"2": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"3": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"4": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"Stage": "A"},{"0": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"1": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"2": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"3": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"4": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"Stage": "B"},{"0": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"1": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"2": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"3": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"4": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"Stage": "C"}];

const result = data.map(({ Stage, ...rest }) => ({ Stage: Object.values(rest) }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: I already added an answer with my suggestion, but that's fine I'll delete it.

Comment: @pilchard Great point! Updated.

Comment: Hmm now i can see true value of destructing using rest and spread. Thanks @A1exandrBelan

Comment: @AlpeshNakrani For example  `data.forEach(({ Stage, ...rest }) => console.log(Stage, rest))`

Answer (score 2):

check this:

```
 const laSolucion = () => {
    const newStructure = [];
    data.forEach(element => {
        // firs capture the values element:
        const propertyValues = Object.values(element);
        // to save each future Stage
        const stageStructure = [];
        propertyValues.forEach(prop => {
            // check if is not the Stage: "string" value
            if( typeof prop === "object") stageStructure.push(prop);
        });
        // add the stage array structure in a array with field Stage
        newStructure.push({"Stage": stageStructure});
    });
    console.log(newStructure);
    return newStructure;
  }
```

Comment: *'check this'* is not an answer, even if the code you included 'works'. Take the time to explain what you've done, how it addresses the OP's question, and any optimizations you've added.

Comment: @pilchard, mmm the "explain part" is in the code :V

Answer (score 1):

As for your code, I tweaked it a bit and now it works as expected.
You had [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35578478/array-prototype-fill-with-object-passes-reference-and-not-new-instance) with the array initialization.

But it's better to use `.map` instead of `.forEach`

```js
let data = [{"0": {"value1": true,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"1": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"2": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"3": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"4": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"Stage": "A"},{"0": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"1": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"2": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"3": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"4": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"Stage": "B"},{"0": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"1": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"2": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"3": {"value1": false,"value2": false,"isSelected": false},"4": {"value1": true,"value2": true,"isSelected": true},"Stage": "C"}];

stagesBackTransform = (data) => {
  //let newArr = new Array(data.length).fill({ Stage: new Array(16) });
  const newArr = [];

  data.forEach((stage, stageIdx) => {
   newArr.push({ Stage: [] });  // <<-- make new object for every item in array
    Object.entries(stage).forEach((item, idx) => {
      if (item[0] !== 'Stage') {
        // newArr[stageIdx].Stage[item[0]] = item[1];
        newArr[stageIdx].Stage[idx] = item[1];
      }
    });
  });
  //console.log('new:', newArr);
  return newArr;
};

console.log(stagesBackTransform(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```