# How to create an array of objects for testing?

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to json and javascript but I have some experience with Java. I wanted to know how to create an array of objects but not sure how to design. What I  want to do is to be able to call

```
object1.field1
```

where `object1` is stored in an array like

```
array = [object1, object2, object3...];
```

and inside object1 would look like

```
object1:
   field1: value1,
   field2: value2,
```

So my question is how would I create the array to hold these values so I can use it for testing? I was thinking either two possible design:

```
array: [
  object1:{
    field1: value1, 
    field2: value2}, 
  object2: {
    field1: value1, 
    field2: value2}]
```

or

```
array: {
  object1:[
    field1: value1, 
    field2: value2], 
  object2: [
    field1: value1, 
    field2: value2]}
```

I was thinking the first one would be correct because it wouldn't be possible to call `object1.field1` if the fields were stored in an array.

Comment: your 2nd option is not valid JS. stick with the first, it's actual code, the 2nd is trying to use an array like it's an object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15742442/declaring-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fist option is correct. You can create

```
let myArray = [
   {
       field1: value1, 
       field2: value2
   }, 
   {
       field1: value1, 
       field2: value2
   }
]
```

However, with a JS array you cannot do myArray.object1, cause this way only access object properties. To access object1 you need to get its index in the array, like myArray[0] gets the array first element, equivalent to object1

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var array = [];
var object = { field1:"value1", field2:"value2" };
array.push(object);
```

or

```
var array = 
[
 {
  field1: "value1", 
  field1: "value2" 
 }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first option is close to the actual code

You define your object by: `var object = {};`

And you can set or get its properties by using `object.field1 = "value1";` or `console.log( object.field1 );`

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need (replace 10 with whatever length you need)

```js
var arrOfObjects = new Array(10).fill({
  field1: 'value1',
  field2: 'value2'
})
```